# Using openseamap as an imageryprovider in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

is there anyway to use openseamap in cesium. the tile map service url: http://t1.openseamap.org/seamark/ gave errors in console such as "http://t1.openseamap.org/seamark/tilemapresource.xml not found" and CoRS error.

Regards
Valimo

Comment: Those links appear to be dead, do you have updated links to test?

Comment: Hi. With my last test, there are always errors in console until I have an appropriate distance of the camera